# How to use qemu to boot up Android in an ARM host?

Tags: android, qemu, arm

I know that I can use the Android emulator, but that requires me to download the entire Android source code and compile it. I tried following how Android boots normally, but the best I got was an infinite bootloop `reboot: Restarting system with command 'bootloader'` -- it seems that I haven't correctly specified the root partition in `-append` and haven't specified the ramdisk correctly (otherwise it should have dropped me into an emergency tty shell), but I have no idea where that would be.
I've been using the images from [here](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sysimg-arm-v8a-direct-download.html).

Here's my qemu configuration so far --

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo qemu-system-aarch64 \
-M virt,accel=hvf,highmem=off -m 7G \
-cpu cortex-a57 \
-kernel arm64-v8a/kernel-ranchu \
-initrd arm64-v8a/ramdisk.img \
-append "rw console=ttyAMA0,38400 keep_bootcon" \
-smp 4 \
-device virtio-gpu-pci,xres=2880,yres=1650 \
-drive file=arm64-v8a/system.img,format=raw,index=0,media=disk  \
-nographic
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just gave up and used Android Studio, which is available for both ARM Macs and ARM Linux.